# Replicate dataframe n number of times and increment another column by 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with more than thousand rows and approx 10 columns. I want to replicate the entire dataframe 20 times and increment index column with each dataframe replication. For example

```
S/No Column1 Column2 Column3
1      123     abc     2.20
1      234     bcd     1.19
1      345     cde     1.22
```

I want to achieve something like below:

```
S/No Column1 Column2 Column3
1      123     abc     2.20
1      234     bcd     1.19
1      345     cde     1.22
2      123     abc     2.20
2      234     bcd     1.19
2      345     cde     1.22
3      123     abc     2.20
3      234     bcd     1.19
3      345     cde     1.22
```

In the above example S/No column is incrementing once end of dataframe is reached not sure if I need to use group by function in order to achieve the above. Have checked few other thread but can only find incrementing values with each row but not based on complete dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines should work:

```
df1=df.copy()
for i in range(1,20):
    df['S/No']=df['S/No']+1
    df1=pd.concat([df1,df])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'S/No':1,
                     'Column1':[123, 234, 345],
                     'Column2':['abc', 'bcd', 'cde'],
                     'Column3':[2.2, 1.19, 1.22]})

data_final = pd.DataFrame()


for i in range(20):
    data_temp = data.copy()
    data_temp.iloc[:, 0] = data_temp.iloc[:, 0] + i
    data_final = data_final.append(data_temp)
```

This is the output:

```
   S/No  Column1 Column2  Column3
0     1      123     abc     2.20
1     1      234     bcd     1.19
2     1      345     cde     1.22
0     2      123     abc     2.20
1     2      234     bcd     1.19
2     2      345     cde     1.22
0     3      123     abc     2.20
1     3      234     bcd     1.19
2     3      345     cde     1.22
```

Answer (score 0):

One line solution:

```
>>> pd.concat([df]*20) \
      .set_index("S/No") \
      .set_index(np.arange(len(df)*20) // 3+1) \
      .rename_axis("S/No") \
      .reset_index()
```

This could be simple if your column `S/No` was a valid python identifier.
Suppose your column name is `S_No`:

```
>>> pd.concat([df]*20) \
      .assign(S_No=np.arange(len(df)*20) // 3+1) \
      .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc) + [`np.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html#numpy-tile):

```
new_df = df.loc[np.tile(df.index, 20)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then fix the `S/No` columns:

```
new_df['S/No'] = (new_df.index // 3) + 1
```

`new_df`:

```
    S/No  Column1 Column2  Column3
0      1      123     abc     2.20
1      1      234     bcd     1.19
2      1      345     cde     1.22
3      2      123     abc     2.20
               ...
55    19      234     bcd     1.19
56    19      345     cde     1.22
57    20      123     abc     2.20
58    20      234     bcd     1.19
59    20      345     cde     1.22
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'S/No': [1, 1, 1],
    'Column1': [123, 234, 345],
    'Column2': ['abc', 'bcd', 'cde'],
    'Column3': [2.2, 1.19, 1.22]
})

new_df = df.loc[np.tile(df.index, 20)].reset_index(drop=True)
new_df['S/No'] = (new_df.index // 3) + 1
print(new_df)
```